# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Cron jobs not working

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to use a cronjob to run a ruby script (Using Rails3 runner) with the following Cronjobs:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    0-59 * * * * echo 'script test'

    # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: test1
    * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/home/administrator/test1/script/rails runner /home/administrator/test1/app/create_flag.rb >> /home/administrator/test1/test.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: test1
```

**test1** is the name of the Rails3 project folder.

the "echo 'script test'" was added as a test, but neither seems to be executing. I'm currently using **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS**.

Have I written the cronjob incorrectly?

Comment: You do have crond running, correct?

Comment: Yes, i believe the command was $ # crond ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crontab file is not a shell script. So you don't need `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file. Plus, spaces there are suspicious. Try something like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=administrator@localhost
BASH_ENV=/home/administrator/.bash_profile

* * * * * /home/administrator/test1/script/rails runner /home/administrator/test1/app/create_flag.rb >> /home/administrator/test1/test.log 2>&1'
```

Plus, make sure you call `crontab -e` as `administrator` to edit the crontab file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the user which runs the commands (you can see the format [here](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html). Also the echo will output 'script test' to what? If you want a test try doing a touch on a file, so you can physically see the action of the cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Cron does not use your user environment, so it will not have the same path set that you have. This means that you should use absolute paths for commands.